# The state of motion of a charge is wrt what?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge

We know that:

- when a charge is at rest it produces an electric field
- when it has a constant velocity it produces a magnetic field
- when it is accelerating it emits EM radiation

These are with respect to what?

Answer (score 1):

The statements you've made (refined slightly) are:

- A charge at rest creates an electric field only;
- A charge moving at constant velocity also creates a magnetic field;  and
- An accelerating charge creates EM radiation.

These statements are true in **any inertial frame.**

A corollary of this is that electric and magnetic fields "mix" with each other when we change between inertial reference frames.  So, for example, one inertial observer might see a charge at rest in their frame, and conclude that the charge only creates an electric field at a particular point $P$.  Another inertial observer would see the charge moving, and might conclude that the same charge creates a magnetic field at $P$ as well.  Both observers are making correct statements in their reference frame.